# Origin of 'jive', 'jive turkey'

Tags: etymology

What's the origin of the word 'jive'? I'm partly confused because I thought "to jive" meant "to go well with," like "that approach jives well with me."

Then someone called me a [jive turkey](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jive+turkey). Is that the same "jive"?

Looking at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jive?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) it's defined as "deceptive, exaggerated, or meaningless talk", "to engage in kidding, teasing, or exaggeration," etc. That works for "jive turkey" but not for what I originally thought "jive" meant. I think that meaning exists, though, as evidenced by the all-powerful [google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jive#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=%22that+jives%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ddfbf15c2e2f4021).

Comment: i'm going to split off the 'jive slang' part, that seems a separate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the "to go well with" meaning is actually a corruption of [jibe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jibe)
a completely different sound alike.

Comment: oo yes now that I think about it, you're right! jibe is the word i was looking for. interesting that a jibe can also be an insult... any relation?

Comment: **jibe** or **gibe** comes from the Middle French word *giber* "to handle roughly, shake, deriv. of *gibe* staff, billhook" the origin of the "in accord" **jibe** is a bit uncertain, it's an americanism, but I think it probably comes from the sailing word used to describe altering the fore and aft sails to match the wind. The variation of that word **gybe** is from the Dutch *gijben*. The confusion is understandable. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Jive" is jazz slang for nonsensical talk. It appears to be derived from the Wolof word "jev", meaning to speak about someone not present, especially disparagingly. Wolof, the main language in Senegal, was spoken by a majority of the slaves brought to America from west Africa.

See, for example, https://www.etymonline.com/word/jive